# curl error 6 when returning from auth authentication in symfony

Tags: curl, oauth-2.0, wamp, symfony4

I am using symfony 4 in wamp installation on win 7. I want to establish an oauth2 connection using [this bundle](https://github.com/knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle) . The problem is that when the user returns back to the site after the authentication the following error appears (the url exists and it is reachable from other applications)

> cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: test.example.gr (see
>   http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

the location of my site is https://localhost/example and my windows host file (if relevant) is:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1   example
::1 example
::1 localhost
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiBmX.png)

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: You're connecting oauth throught which site ?

Comment: from my localhost project in wamp server to an external service

Comment: What is this external service ? What did you define as return oauth URL ?

Comment: It is an insurance carrier of the state. I defined the return url based on the instructions from the organisation itself

Comment: Yes and what is this URL ?

Comment: After further investigation it seems that it is a proxy authentication issue settings in wamp.